# Can an npm/yarn project depend on a git repo which hasn't been built?

Tags: javascript, git, github, npm, yarnpkg

We are developing a Vue component library for use in our team's apps. It's open source but it doesn't make sense to actively distribute it to the community. Firstly because it's only valuable to us, secondly because we want a simple development procedure with small iterations.

I figure we should `yarn add` it from its GitHub repo url, and not publish it to NPM. What confuses me with that approach is how to get it built? Would I have to build the library and add its `dist/` to git? Or create a GitHub release any time I want to update an app that uses the library? Or can I easily build a dependency from the depending app's dev env?

(I have tried `yarn add author/repo#branch` but it doesn't build `node_modules/repo/dist`. I have no prior experience in publishing to NPM.)

Comment: I'm not sure your approach is that good here. I'd advise you to host your own NPM repo - you can then add whatever packages to it that aren't available on the world wide NPM. It's only going to be internal. You would need some build step that also publishes to your private repo but it could be manual if your libraries don't change much. Or automated - that's what I'd probably go for, since you should aim to have an automated pipeline anyway, so adding one library to be built + privately published shouldn't be much work.

Comment: I use npm 6 to depend on local private git submodules. e.g. `npm install @modules/foo@..\..\modules\foo --save`  (Note: [doesn't work in npm 7 or later](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2339))